# Empty server response with cntlm proxy and basic auth params in url for yum repo

Tags: proxy, basic-authentication, datastax, yum

I am using cntlm proxy on a *CentOs 7* server behind a corporate proxy which needs an authentication.

Here is my cntlm.conf file :

```
Username    user
Domain      dom
Auth        NTLMv2
PassNTLMv2  **********

Proxy       corporateproxy:8080
NoProxy     localhost, 127.0.0.*, 10.*, 192.168.*, 172.*, *.local

Listen      0.0.0.0:3128
```

Everything works ok, except for a yum repo who needs a basic auth :

```
[datastax-cassandra]
name=datastax-cassandra
humanname=DataStax Repo for DataStax Enterprise
baseurl= http://auser@mail.com:s6pZ4cjORRAqDhG@rpm.datastax.com/entreprise
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

When running

```
repoquery --plugins --queryformat '%{NAME}_|-%{VERSION}_|-%{RELEASE}_|-%{ARCH}_|-%{REPOID}'   --pkgnarrow=available selinux-policy-devel policycoreutils-python
```

I get :

```
Could not match packages: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from datastax-cassandra: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://auser@email.com:s6pZ4cjORRAqDhG@rpm.datastax.com/enterprise/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#52 - "Empty reply from server"
```

For any other mirror server which do not need basic auth, everything is ok.

Any idea (cntlm configuration, yum repo configuration, ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a patch for cntlm with support for Basic HTTP Auth; see
[cntlm-0.35.1 modified to support Basic HTTP Auth with HTTPAUTH parameter](http://www.naresh.se/2010/12/08/cntlm-0-35-1-modified-to-support-basic-http-auth-with-httpauth-parameter/)

Comment: Thank you for this answer ! Hopefully I am no more using a corporate firewall, so I can not test this patch and validate your answer, but I am sure someone else will do it !